# Intermittent connectivity to a SunOS 4.1.4 virtual machine

Tags: networking, virtual-machine, solaris

I am running SunOS 4.1.4 (those were the days...) under QEMU, networked via a `tap` device on the host. I'm starting the vm like this...

```
qemu-system-sparc \
    -rtc base=utc \
    -drive file=sunos-root.img,format=raw,bus=0,unit=0 \
    -drive file=sunos-home.img,format=raw,bus=0,unit=1 \
    -drive file=sunos-gnu.img,format=raw,bus=0,unit=2 \
    -nic tap,br=virbr0,helper=/usr/libexec/qemu-bridge-helper \
    -nographic
```

...and everything works great, except for networking, which seems to work only sporadically.

When SunOS comes up, it is running, among other things, a telnet server and and rshell server via `inetd`. The tap interface is attached to bridge `virbr0` (`192.1681.22.1`), and the SunOS vm is assigned `192.168.122.103`:

```
bash-3.2# ifconfig le0
le0: flags=63<UP,BROADCAST,NOTRAILERS,RUNNING>
        inet 192.168.122.103 netmask ffffff00 broadcast 192.168.122.255
        ether 52:54:0:12:34:56
```

If I'm lucky, I can simply  `telnet 192.168.122.103` (or `rsh`) from the host and it Just Works. Other times, it doesn't, and I can't figure out why. If I run this in a loop...

```
while ! rsh -l root 192.168.122.103 /bin/true; do
  sleep 1
done
```

...it will *eventually* work.

Outbound traffic *from* the virtual machine always works (I can, e.g., reliably `telnet 192.168.122.1 22` to get the `SSH-2.0-OpenSSH...` banner from my host). Running `tcpdump` on the tap interface when failing to telnet to the vm, I see:

```
18:39:07.584861 IP 192.168.122.1.40270 > 192.168.122.103.telnet: Flags [S], seq 2038492576, win 64240, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 2376785260 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0
18:39:07.585177 IP 192.168.122.103.telnet > 192.168.122.1.40270: Flags [S.], seq 2034944001, ack 2038492577, win 4096, options [mss 1460], length 0
18:39:07.585205 IP 192.168.122.1.40270 > 192.168.122.103.telnet: Flags [.], ack 1, win 64240, length 0
18:39:07.585279 IP 192.168.122.1.40270 > 192.168.122.103.telnet: Flags [P.], seq 1:28, ack 1, win 64240, length 27 [telnet DO SUPPRESS GO AHEAD, WILL TERMINAL TYPE, WILL NAWS, WILL TSPEED, W
ILL LFLOW, WILL LINEMODE, WILL NEW-ENVIRON, DO STATUS, WILL XDISPLOC [|telnet]
18:39:07.773325 IP 192.168.122.103.telnet > 192.168.122.1.40270: Flags [.], ack 28, win 4069, length 0
18:39:10.323018 IP 192.168.122.1.40270 > 192.168.122.103.telnet: Flags [P.], seq 28:30, ack 1, win 64240, length 2
18:39:10.373287 IP 192.168.122.103.telnet > 192.168.122.1.40270: Flags [.], ack 30, win 4067, length 0
18:39:11.401927 IP 192.168.122.1.40270 > 192.168.122.103.telnet: Flags [P.], seq 30:32, ack 1, win 64240, length 2
18:39:11.573256 IP 192.168.122.103.telnet > 192.168.122.1.40270: Flags [.], ack 32, win 4065, length 0
18:39:12.672424 IP 192.168.122.1.40270 > 192.168.122.103.telnet: Flags [P.], seq 32:34, ack 1, win 64240, length 2
18:39:12.773266 IP 192.168.122.103.telnet > 192.168.122.1.40270: Flags [.], ack 34, win 4063, length 0
```

So you can see that there appears to be traffic passing back and forth, but it's still not working. This is what it looks like when things are successful:

```
18:41:38.435167 IP 192.168.122.1.40282 > 192.168.122.103.telnet: Flags [S], seq 404147648, win 64240, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 2376936111 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0
18:41:38.435489 IP 192.168.122.103.telnet > 192.168.122.1.40282: Flags [S.], seq 2054336001, ack 404147649, win 4096, options [mss 1460], length 0
18:41:38.435525 IP 192.168.122.1.40282 > 192.168.122.103.telnet: Flags [.], ack 1, win 64240, length 0
18:41:38.435585 IP 192.168.122.1.40282 > 192.168.122.103.telnet: Flags [P.], seq 1:28, ack 1, win 64240, length 27 [telnet DO SUPPRESS GO AHEAD, WILL TERMINAL TYPE, WILL NAWS, WILL TSPEED, W
ILL LFLOW, WILL LINEMODE, WILL NEW-ENVIRON, DO STATUS, WILL XDISPLOC [|telnet]
18:41:38.459878 IP 192.168.122.103.telnet > 192.168.122.1.40282: Flags [P.], seq 1:4, ack 28, win 4069, length 3 [telnet DO TERMINAL TYPE [|telnet]
18:41:38.459971 IP 192.168.122.1.40282 > 192.168.122.103.telnet: Flags [.], ack 4, win 64237, length 0
18:41:38.460564 IP 192.168.122.103.telnet > 192.168.122.1.40282: Flags [P.], seq 4:34, ack 28, win 4096, length 30 [telnet WILL SUPPRESS GO AHEAD, DONT NAWS, DONT TSPEED, DONT LFLOW, DONT LI
NEMODE, DONT NEW-ENVIRON, WONT STATUS, DONT XDISPLOC, SB TERMINAL TYPE SEND SE [|telnet]
```

You can see that this time the Telnet protocol exchange compltes successfully.

It's not a firewall issue (I added a `-j ACCEPT` rule at the top of the `INPUT` chain, there are no restrictions on `OUTPUT`, and this traffic won't hit the `FORWARD` chain).

Maybe the QEMU lance ethernet driver is just buggy?

Comment: There is traffic at the tcp layer, but telnetd doesn't seem to reply to the banner negotiation. Does a truss on telnetd show that it received the client hello? I wonder if the interface might start up in some weird mode where the hello isn't tranferred properly (similar to automatic LF→CRLF translations), you might want to compare a tcpdump from the host to one captured from inside the VM.